# using ms Access functions in visual studio's query builder

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

How can I use my custom ms-Access functions in visual studio's query builder? It works fine in Access, but when I've tried to use it to create TableAdapter it said "Undefined function". I've tried to make view and use "select * from testview1", which ended with same result. Turning "allow to use all macro" on doesn't work either. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the query within an Access app or a .NET app using an Access database as it's backing store?

Custom functions are only available within Access itself.  When a query is run against Access from .NET, the custom functions are not available.

If you need custom functions, move to SQL Server Express (or move anyways, not much reason to still use Access).

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to still use Access, not the least that Jet is installed by default with Windows. In addition, it is familiar to non-technical people so very low-cost set-ups in small companies are possible.

Comment: I do not think that all the type of custom functions that can be built in Access VBA can be built in SQL Server Express.

Comment: @Remou, it is not true that Jet is included in every version of Windows by default anymore.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/01/21/how-to-get-a-x64-version-of-jet.aspx